# Auto update isn't working in VSCode: Could not create temporary directory: Permission denied

Tags: visual-studio-code, access-rights

From certain point I started getting this error from time to time(I suppose it fires when editor tries to check for updates), and manual/auto update doesn't work. The only way I can update the editor is re-download the app and replace it manually.

Does someone face same issue and successfully resolved?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Try to type the following commands in a terminal:

```
cd ~/Library/Caches

sudo chown -R $(whoami):staff *
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, could you explain in your answer(or comment) what is in this directory and what is `:staff` ?

Comment: chown changeowner .  -R recursion  * for all in this directory  And you user with group stuff become founder of all in this directory

Comment: This did the trick for me. There was actually several files/folders in the `~/Library/Caches` folder owned by `root:staff`.

Comment: how to handle when having multiple admin users on the macOS, the folder is with permission to user X and i'm user Y. should I just set the folder 775?

Comment: @pakhilov what do you have to say about barney74's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59269643/13929340) ?

Comment: thank you, @jcuypers, but which username is it? where can i locate the username i am using?

Comment: `sudo chown -R <username>:staff *` - in what directory is this supposed to be executed? home?

Comment: This one solves this error too:
"Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'instanceId' in 0" with a python debugger on vscode

Comment: Didn't have `com.microsoft.VSCode.ShipIt` but `Microsoft` directory, received some permission denied for some apple objects, and VS Code is still complaining `Could not create temporary directory: Permission denied` with a sub-message `Source: update service`. VS Code 1.72.1.

Comment: `find ~/Library/Caches -uid 0` outputs the files/directories being owned by root (uid 0)

Answer (score 79):

The above solution works, but it is like using a sledge hammer to kill a house fly.

1. Go to Caches `cd ~/Library/Caches`.
2. Check ownership of folders. `ls -la`
3. You will probably see `drwxr--r-- 2 root staff 64 Nov 15 09:37 com.microsoft.VSCode.ShipIt`
4. Run `sudo chown <username>:staff com.microsoft.VSCode.ShipIt`

This allows you to only update that folder owner and won't touch the other folders. You can break over item unexpectedly.

Comment: If you're using VSCodium, the cache folder to fix is `com.visualstudio.code.oss.ShipIt`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: @bzx agreed! This is a better solution

Answer (score 10):

In my case, `~/Library/Caches/com.microsoft.VSCode.ShipIt` was owned by `root:staff` all of a sudden. I fixed it by running the following command:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:'staff' ~/Library/Caches/com.microsoft.VSCode.ShipIt
```

(added single quotes around the group name because ZSH didn't like it)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with update `VSCode` after supplemental update and bug fixes for my `macOS Catalina 10.15.6` on 12.08.2020. I solved the problem with the manual update `VSCode`:

1. goto [last changes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates) on the official site.
2. Downloads: <s>Windows: User System</s>| **Mac** | <s>Linux: snap deb rpm tarball</s>
3. `mv ~/Downloads/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/ ~/Applications/` or move/copy `Visual Studio Code.app` into `Applications` folder
4. Launch the `Visual Studio Code.app` and enjoy the latest version.

> After that, the application should `auto update` the new version without any problems !

Answer (score 0):

I use the following script to manually download/install the new version (e.g. under `/opt/`). The old dir is backed-up. Also in case of network failure I can rerun the script to resume.

`vscode-update`

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e
cd /opt/
datetime=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%m%S")
dateonly=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
downloadedfile="vscode_download_$dateonly.tar.gz"
backupfile="VSCode-linux-x64_backup_$datetime"
url=https://update.code.visualstudio.com/latest/linux-x64/stable


echo "Downloading $url --> $(pwd)/$downloadedfile"
wget --continue -O "$downloadedfile" $url

echo "backing up old vscode under: $backupfile"
mv VSCode-linux-x64/ "$backupfile"

echo "extracting: $downloadedfile"
tar xvzf "$downloadedfile"

echo "UPDATE DONE!"
```